# Being read to me and being read to

Tags: gerunds, ellipsis, transitivity

Here is a sentence:

> 1. I enjoy when someone read to me.

I think the passive form of this sentence could be:

> 2. I enjoy being read to me.

I found the following sentence where "me" is omited as:

> 3. The pleasure of being read to.

Source: http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/the-pleasures-of-being-read-to

I think this sentence should be:

> The pleasure of being read to me.

So, why the pronoun 'me' is omited in sentence No 3 ?

Comment: Your second sentence is incorrect. The pronoun _me_ is not necessary here. It should be: _"I enjoy being read to."_ The pronoun _me_ is not omitted in the sentence _"The pleasure of being read to."_ Why do you think it should be there?

Comment: **Active** : I feel pleasure when someone reads to me **passive** I feel pleasur being read to me.

Why 'me' isn't necessary in the passive sentence ?

Comment: Please tell us why you think the pronoun should be used. Of what verb do you think the pronoun is the object? The object of the elided preposition _in_ is the NP _being read to._ There is no need for an objective pronoun here.

Comment: Also, _"I feel pleasure (in) being read to"_ is not the passive form of _"I feel pleasure when someone reads to me."_ That would be _"Pleasure is felt by me when I am read to by someone."_

Comment: @P.E Dent I didn't know that before.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence should be:

> I enjoy when someone read**s** to me.

For verb agreement. The second sentence doesn't need the second "me", so

> I enjoy being read to.

The third sentence is a fragment and could be:

> The pleasure of being read to is why I love audiobooks.

It doesn't need a "me".